# I would user profile using Google Access Token using api https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-signin

I would like to get user profile using Google Access Token using api https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo

The question is, is it safe to use https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo

If there is another way to get user profile using Google Access Token please suggest.

Comment: use the people api